# Aptana duplicate line shortcut

Tags: duplicates, line, aptana

How can i duplicate line in Aptana into a new line?
In notepad++ i can use `CTRL+D` to duplicate, but not in `aptana`. Any hotkeys for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> CTRL + SHIFT + D

or

> Commands -> Text -> Duplicate Line / Selection

If you find anything missing in Aptana (or Eclipse for that matter), you can always expand functionality on your own.
[Read documentation for specifics](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Customizing+Studio).

Comment: Thanks for response, it works if is selected, but can i duplicate it without selecting? :)

Comment: Yes, you can. Just put the cursor anywhere - without making the selection - and you will duplicate whole line using this command.

If it doesn't work. What programming language are you testing that with and what Aptana version do you have (Help -> About Aptana to find the build version)?

Comment: It works. I'm using Aptana on version 3 :) Thank you so much :)